# YouTube API for commercial use, storing data from YouTube API locally

Tags: android, ios, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am curious. Can I use YouTube API for **commercial use** in a way: I will have Android/iOS app, which will be free on Google Play/App Store. This app will contain embedded videos from YouTube. I get all emmbed links from YouTube API. All videos will be unlisted, but they will be playlist, so I can get them from API.

In the future, **I plan to add ADs to my application or create some kind of subscription payment for accessing application.** Is to ok to use YouTube API for this kind of stuff?

Also my next question is: I would like to **store locally on phone** some kind of data like **"Video ID, thumbnail URL, embedd url"** for some time - There will be timer or something which will call API when new data will be required. It will be some kind of local cache. Is it okay with Terms of Service of YouTube API? Or do I need to call API everytime I want data?

Thanks

Comment: I have created an application using the Youtube API some time before with the features you just mentioned above. As far as I know, there will be no violation of terms and conditions, but you have to make sure you don't use any videos which are pirated or having third party privacy issues. Also,  you will have to use a Youtube API key to play your videos. So even if you store the URLs in your local DB you will be dependent on Youtube at the end of the day. So the chances of you meeting with a violation of terms is low I think.

Comment: I will fetch only videos from my channel. Or do you think there is better service for this kind of stuff? I looked up Vimeo, but it documentation seems little bit confusing. Oh and I forgot to say, that I dont want to create and use my backend. I just want user to download app and he will see content from API

Comment: Did you manage to have your quota increased for Youtube API for commercial use? What are the approx costs? Is it pay per usage of api queries?